# Simplest way to get the first n elements of an iterator

Tags: python, iterator, generator

How can I get the first *n* elements of an iterator (generator) in the simplest way?  Is there something simpler than, e. g.

```
def firstN(iterator, n):
  for i in range(n):
    yield iterator.next()

print list(firstN(it, 3))
```

I can't think of a nicer way, but maybe there is?  Maybe a functional form?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```py
from itertools import islice
print(list(islice(it, 3)))
```

This will yield the next 3 elements from `it`, then stop.

Answer (score 2):

Without using `itertools`:

```
(t[0] for t in zip(L, range(3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've come up myself now with this:

```
[ iterator.next() for i in range(3) ]
```

(or just with `(…)` instead of `[…]` if you just need another iterator.)

And I think it suits me just fine.

Comment: The main disadvantage is that this way I cannot use a complex expression for the iterator (like `iter(range(4))` or the call of a generator) because it would get evaluated in each comprehension iteration anew and thus create a new iterator.  But I can live with this.

Comment: It also only works for iterators, giving error in case of a list

Comment: I only asked for a version for an iterator.  If my value could be a list, I can always use `iter(value)` to ensure that it's an iterator.  For iterators, `iter(x)` returns `x`.

Comment: Yes, but you've to do that outside as of course `(iter(x).next() for i in range(3))` doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, that's right and exactly the cumbersomeness I meant in my first comment.  But in my current usecase, the iterator comes and I know that it's an iterator.  And one always can use the comprehension local variable hack:  `[ iterator.next() for iterator in [iter(value)] for i in range(3) ]` (but I dislike this solution of course and would not propose it in an answer, for a comment, though, it's good enough).